# TypeError: "string" must be a string, Buffer, or ArrayBuffer

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, chai

Developed a Node proxy app using [Multiparty](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multiparty) NPM module for multipart/form-data. I would like to test the application using [Mocha](https://mochajs.org/) and [Chai](http://chaijs.com/). While running the test case I am getting the "TypeError: "string" must be a string, Buffer, or ArrayBuffer" error.

My code snippet is:

```
it('<test case description comes here>', (done) => {
    chai.request(app)
            .post('<my post url comes here>')
            .set('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data; boundary=' + Math.random())
            .send({emailField: 'test@xyz.com', xyzField: 'Some Data'})
            .attach('file', 'test.txt')
            .end((error, result) => {
                if (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
                result.should.have.status(200);
                result.should.not.be.empty;
                done();
            });
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I believe this is because your `.attach` cannot be a string. It needs to be a buffer.

Comment: Thanks @LostJon. Is there any way to make it buffer? Most of the answers suggesting attach, so I used attach property.

Comment: should look like `.attach('file', fs.readFileSync('test.txt'))`. This is a guess, im not sure what the **filetypes** can be bc it isnt listed on the chai-http module. SRC: https://github.com/chaijs/chai-http

Comment: I would honestly look at using `request` or `request-promise` as a node lib for doing http requests. you would then use mocha/chai to do your assertions.